# how to hide button create/edit in module employee to employee who belongs to group Employee/employee?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

i develop a custom module  to restrict the right to create a new employee or to modify an existing one to the employees who belongs to group "Employee/Employee" but i notice even though my employee has the right "Employee/Manager" he became not able to create or edit employees. How can i fix that problem ? Any idea for help please ? 
here is my code :

hr_employee_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<record id="view_hr_employee_form_remove_edit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.hr.employee.form.remove.edit</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="edit">false</attribute>
            <attribute name="create">false</attribute>

        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="view_hr_employee_tree_remove_edit_create" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.hr.employee.tree.remove.edit.create</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_tree"/>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_user')])]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//tree" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="edit">false</attribute>
            <attribute name="create">false</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="view_hr_employee_kanban_remove_edit_create" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.hr.employee.kanban.remove.edit.create</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.hr_kanban_view_employees"/>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_user')])]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//kanban" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="edit">false</attribute>
            <attribute name="create">false</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>

</odoo>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide button create/edit from XML. Like the following:

```
<field name="your_field_name" options="{'no_create_edit':True}" />
```

I hope this helps you. Thank you.

Comment: My  problem is the button will be hidden for all employees groups

Answer (score 2):

Add this rule to your module, it will hide the button 'create' only for the hr_user group and not for hr_manager group, you should create new file security.xml, where you can past this rule

```
  <record id="rule_security_groups_hr_user" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">User can't edit or create employees.</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="hr.model_hr_employee"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('hr.group_hr_user'))]"/>
        <field name="perm_read" eval="1"/>
        <field name="perm_create" eval="0"/>
        <field name="perm_write" eval="0"/>
        <field name="perm_unlink" eval="0" />
        <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
    </record>
```

I hope this helps you. good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the user is always able to create or edit the employees

Comment: did you declare the security.xml file in the __ manifest __.py file ?

Comment: I tested it, it works correctly , you should review your code

Comment: There was another rules that make a conflict with this rule. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your technique work when the users don't have that group but
as you know every user have that group and you cannot remove it.

You should use Odoo sercurity to Do this.

One thing by default Users that don't belong to Officer they don't have access to create

```
  access_hr_employee_system_user,hr.employee system user,model_hr_employee,base.group_user,1,0,0,0
  access_hr_employee_user,hr.employee user,model_hr_employee,group_hr_user,1,1,1,1
```

So If you mean that only manager can create an employee you should do this

1. change access right of Officer group  (target the ID `hr.access_hr_employee_user`)

   `hr.access_hr_employee_user,hr.employee user,model_hr_employee,group_hr_user,1,0,0,0`
2. Give manager full access rights

   `access_hr_employee_manger,hr.employee manager,model_hr_employee,hr.group_hr_manager,1,1,1,1`

This why only manager can Create or update employees.

Comment: Although i use these security rules my problem is the same. All the employee groups will be not able to create/create employees. i don't know where the problem come from.

Comment: You can check the security access on your model using Odoo developer mode and see where the problem exactly

Comment: Should i modify the file ir.model.access.csv in the existing module (hr) or creating a new module with these rules ?

Comment: no create a new one is better this why I used  `hr.access_hr_employee_user` like this we change the same rule that was created by `hr` module.

Comment: When i use your rules it shows error : **No matching record found for external id 'group_hr_user' in field 'Group'**

Comment: sorry about that because it was created in `hr` you need to give the full XML-ID `hr.group_hr_user` just correct the first rule

Comment: `...,hr.group_hr_user,1,0,0,0` always when you need to get a record by xml-id you need to give full name

Comment: even though i use this group it has always possibility to create and edit employees

Comment: can you post a photo of odoo security rules of hr.employee

Comment: yes I knew It should work because Odoo security is so powerful .